# Change width of a table column with 320andup

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Using [320andup](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/), I have a table with 2 columns. I'd like to make a column wider.

Is there a best practice for that? 
I fear that by using `<col width="100">` this will mess up with the responsive design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `col width` attribute **[isn't supported anymore](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_col_width.asp)** (as of HTML5), so it's definitely not the way to go, especially if your website is going to be responsive-design oriented.

A better alternative would be to just give both the col's a common class, and set the preferred width accordingly for that class inside your CSS file, E.g.

**HTML**

```
<col class="theCols">
```

**CSS**

```
.theCols {
  width:70%;
}
```